# ubuntu 12.04 installation alongside windows 7

Tags: installation

I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 alongside windows 7. I downloaded Ubuntu and burned it in DVD, but when I tried to install it (I used both Try Ubuntu and Install Ubuntu options.), only purple screen with Ubuntu logo comes and nothing happens.
Note:1.The Downloaded Ubuntu works fine in virtual box.
If something goes wrong, I don't have windows 7 DVD to repair the loader problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have uefi-bios ?!

Here is explained the most about uefi-bios.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

In bios-settings (mostly to get there with key 'F2' - to see which key - look at 
booting of BIOS) ...

you should disable uefi-bios
and enable efi-bios.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you have not burnt iso image properly. Or it might be a problem with your DVD Drive. You can check the DVD on another PC.